# alert box javascript won't close because window.onload

Tags: javascript

I'm new to Javascript and now im experimenting with countdown timer. Everytime the countdown finsihed, the page pop alert box that says: countdown finished. But everytime i click OK, the alert box won't close. I assume it has something to do with `windows.onload` function but i don't know how to fix it.

```js
function startTimer(duration, display) {
  var timer = duration,
    minutes,
    seconds;

  setInterval(function() {
    minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10);
    seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

    minutes = minutes < 10 ? '0' + minutes : minutes;
    seconds = seconds < 10 ? '0' + seconds : seconds;

    display.textContent = minutes + ':' + seconds;

    if (--timer < 0) {
      timer = 0;
      alert('countdown finished');
      document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = 'EXPIRED';
    }
  }, 1000);
}

window.onload = function() {
  var fiveMinutes = 60 * 0.1,
    //display = document.querySelector('#time');
    display = document.getElementById('demo');
  startTimer(fiveMinutes, display);
};
```

```html
<h1>conutdown</h1>
<p id="demo"></p>
<!-- <div>Registration closes in <span id="time">05:00</span> minutes!</div> -->
```

Comment: Do note that the interval isn't really firing after a second because javascript is one-threaded. What interval in javascript is doing is "add this to the executing queue after a second", but if you got something really heavy going on, then it will lead to a missync. Also, if the computer is going to sleep, the interval will stop.

So you need to a) save the time (through Date), and then constantly b) check the current time at every interval loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to clear the interval using `clearInterval()`

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>countdown</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>countdown</h1>
    <p id="demo"></p>
    <!-- <div>Registration closes in <span id="time">05:00</span> minutes!</div> -->

<script>

function startTimer(duration, display) {
  var timer = duration,
    minutes,
    seconds;

var intrvl = setInterval(function() {
    minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10);
    seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

    minutes = minutes < 10 ? '0' + minutes : minutes;
    seconds = seconds < 10 ? '0' + seconds : seconds;

    display.textContent = minutes + ':' + seconds;

    if (--timer < 0) {
      timer = 0;
      alert('countdown finished');
      document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = 'EXPIRED';
      clearInterval(intrvl); // Clears interval
    }
  }, 1000);
}

window.onload = function() {
  var fiveMinutes = 60 * 0.1,
    //display = document.querySelector('#time');
    display = document.getElementById('demo');
  startTimer(fiveMinutes, display);
};

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to `clearInterval` after the time is up. Otherwise, the `setInterval` won't stop firing your callback. Try something like this:

```
function startTimer(duration, display) {
  var timer = duration,
    minutes,
    seconds;

  var interval = setInterval(function() { // <-- `var interval =` is important
    minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10);
    seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

    minutes = minutes < 10 ? '0' + minutes : minutes;
    seconds = seconds < 10 ? '0' + seconds : seconds;

    display.textContent = minutes + ':' + seconds;

    if (--timer < 0) {
      timer = 0;
      alert('countdown finished');
      document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = 'EXPIRED';
      clearInterval(interval); // <-- this is also important
    }
  }, 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you don't clear the interval. So if your timer is over, you still call the check for "is my timer lower than 0" and display the Interval.

Basic JS for clearing an interval:

```
var myInterval = setInterval(function(){...}, 1000);
clearInterval(myVar); //the interval won't be called again
```

```js
function startTimer(duration, display) {
  var timer = duration,
    minutes,
    seconds;

  var myInterval = setInterval(function() {
    minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10);
    seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

    minutes = minutes < 10 ? '0' + minutes : minutes;
    seconds = seconds < 10 ? '0' + seconds : seconds;

    display.textContent = minutes + ':' + seconds;

    if (--timer < 0) {
      timer = 0;
      console.log('countdown finished');
      document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = 'EXPIRED';
      clearInterval(myInterval)
      
    }
  }, 1000);
}

window.onload = function() {
  var fiveMinutes = 60 * 0.1,
    //display = document.querySelector('#time');
    display = document.getElementById('demo');
  startTimer(fiveMinutes, display);
};
```

```html
<h1>conutdown</h1>
<p id="demo"></p>
<!-- <div>Registration closes in <span id="time">05:00</span> minutes!</div> -->
```